# Como devolver un string en una función de un Dll escrito en Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-2010

Estoy tratando de crear un DLL en Delphi 10.3 que pueda ser consumido por un programa llamado IFER Field-Map, un software creado en Delphi.

En la documentación oficial del software dice que en el dll debe ser implementado una función llamada FunctionCaptionW()  (No se especifica que deba recibir parametros) de tipo PAnsiChar, la cual va a devolver lo que se verá como el titulo del dll importado y no entiendo muy bien como funciona esto de los dll. Desearía poder devolver el string directamente. He creado esta función.

```
function FunctionCaptionW() :PAnsiChar; export;stdcall;

  // Esta es la descripción en ingles de lo que debe devolver la función
  // returns a module caption which will be displayed in extension menu

 var
    test: array[0..3] of Char;
    mychar: PAnsiChar;


 begin
    test := 'test';
    // Esto era para asegurarme que efectivamente la funcion es llamada.
    ShowMessage(test);
    myChar := @text[0];

    RESULT := myChar;
 end;



// al final del archivo exporto la función
exports FunctionCaptionW;
```

Pero a la hora de importarla en el software aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También estaría agradecido si pudieran recomendarme documentación donde pueda leer acerca de como crear archivos dll. Gracias y buen día.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de probar un rato he logrado que apareciera el texto en el programa.

```
function FunctionCaptionW():PWideChar; export;stdcall;
  // Esta es la descripción en ingles de lo que debe devolver la función
  // returns a module caption which will be displayed in extension menu
 var
    test: string;
    mychar: PWideChar;
 begin
    test := 'test';
    myChar := @test[1];
    RESULT := myChar;
 end;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]